# How do I add unique id values to query loop block post template tags?

Tags: full-site-editing

I am using WordPress 6+ with a full-site editor theme.

I need to add the post slug as the id for each post in the query loop block.

Must I extend the block for such a trivial task?

Comment: I don't see any way to do it in the UI. Can I ask why you need it?

Comment: I want to be able to add internal links so I don’t have to link to the page and then someone scroll down to the block.